# Writing to CSV through java

Tags: java, csv

When writing a column name into a CSV file through java the space between two words in a column comes up as double quotation marks...

eg. test_data[0][36] = "True Accept"; displays as True" Accept in the csv file..

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Here is the code:

```
private void writeToCSV() throws IOException {
   CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("list_of_churners.csv"),',',' '); 
   String [] data = new String[40]; 
   for(int i=0;i<341;i++)
   { 
      for(int k=0;k<40;k++)
      {      
         data[k] = test_data[i][k]; 
      }
      writer.writeNext(data); 
   }
   writer.close()
}
```

**EDIT:**  Here is the solution:

**CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("list_of_churners.csv"),',','\t ');**

Changing space ' ' to '\t' fixes the problem.

Comment: post your code that does the file writing.

Comment: What library are you using to write the CSV file? Also, post your code please.

Comment: private void writeToCSV() throws IOException{  
  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("list_of_churners.csv"),',',' ');
  String [] data = new String[40];
  for(int i=0;i<341;i++){
   for(int k=0;k<40;k++){
    data[k]=test_data[i][k];
   }
   writer.writeNext(data);
  }
  writer.close();
 }

Comment: You can (and should) edit you original question instead of posting the code in a comment. I did that for you. For future reference, check out the formatting FAQs http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and the general FAQs at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Use a framework for writing and reading CSV files. I recommend [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).